# Error while uploading hex file to AVR uC

Tags: avr, linux, programmer, attiny, avrdude

I am trying to upload a hex file to an ATtiny85 from Ubuntu by running these commands:

```
avr-gcc -mmcu=attiny85 -Wall -Os -o src.elf main.cpp
avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex src.elf src.hex
avrdude -p t85 -c avrispmkII -e -U flash:w:src.hex
```

I get this error:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't set attributes for device "/dev/ttyS0": Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I tried to use different USB ports, but that didn't help. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try using 'sudo' before the avrdude command, you might have your usb permissions a little whacky. Also you may need to make sure you're using the right port which you can override with the -P flag to avrdude.

Comment: Nope, 'sudo' did not work...

Comment: You might see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929587/avr-isp-mkii-avrdude-ubuntu-11-10  Can't really help you with the AVRISP beyond that so removed my answer which applied more to stk500 style USB serial programmers/Arduino ISP sketches.

Comment: ) Unplug your programmer; 2) On the command line enter `sudo dmesg -c`; 3) Plug in your programmer; 4) On the command line enter `sudo dmesg -c  again and copy its output into your question.

Comment: This is pretty easy to solve once you know what to look for. Consider joining us in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering I can talk you through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short write-up from chat.

First make sure the driver module is loaded, apparently this does not happen automatically:

**Option 1:** On the fly: `modprobe cdc-acm`

**Option 2:** To load the module at boot time:

- `sudo bash -c 'echo hoi >> /etc/modules` Notice the **double** `>>` is important.
- reboot
- check if the module is loaded: `lsmod | grep cdc-acm && echo success || echo failed`

---

You should be able to program the device using:

```
sudo avrdude -v -p t85 -c avrispmkII -P usb -U flash:w:src.hex
```

Check this question for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412727/avrisp-mkii-doesnt-work-with-avrdude-in-linux

Not sure what the reason is for the error message you reported at this point:

```
avrdude: stk500v2_command(): command failed
avrdude: stk500v2_program_enable(): bad AVRISPmkII connection status: Target not detected
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
```

---

Your to do list:

1. Automatically load the cdc-acm module => Described above.
2. Figure out what is wrong with your `udev` rules, so you do not have to use `sudo` for programming => check https://askubuntu.com/ for that.
3. Figure out why the programmer doesn't respond. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ is the right place. A picture of your setup will help. As it is a different error than you started with, I think a new question is justified.