# Can't upload program to ATmega16

Tags: avr, atmega, avrdude

I have the same exact problem as in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67576/error-while-uploading-hex-file-to-avr-uc), except that I have an ATmega16 microcontroller. But the answer on that question doesn't solve my problem. ie:

The command: `avrdude -c avrisp -p m16` results in the following error message:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't set attributes for device "/dev/ttyS0":
    Inappropriate ioctl for device
avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I don't whether to ask the question is right but I badly need an answer to this problem.

After connecting the device `lsusb`, I get the following:

```
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 16c0:05dc VOTI shared ID for use with libusb
```

Comment: are you sure that the UART isn't /dev/ttyUSB0 ?

Comment: my programmer is a usb device and `avrdude -p m16 -c avrisp -P "/dev/ttyUSB0"` shows following `avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyUSB0": No such file or directory` and `avrdude -p m16 -c avrisp -P usb` shows 
`avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "usb": No such file or directory
`


`

Comment: ls /dev/ttyU* ?

Comment: `/dev/ttyS0` is the hardware UART built into the PC.  You should only be using that if you have plugged something in to the 9-pin socket on the back of your computer.  It may be `/dev/ttyUSB0`, `/dev/ttyACM0` or similar depending on the device.

Comment: @BrianDrummond there is no any file or folder `/dev/ttyU*`

Comment: What device are you using to program? A usb-to-serial, or a usb-ICSP?

Comment: Usb Isp Programmer.

Comment: The linked question was answered with `-P usb` - does this not work for you?

Comment: yeah that doesn't work as I already said in earlier comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this is that I had been using USBASP programmer. So instead of

```
avrdude -c avrisp -p m16
```

I needed to run the following command

```
avrdude -c usbasp -p m16
```